# Multiple layers in JSON with System.Web.Helpers

Tags: c#

I've been using a service that returns a JSON file with an array inside and object in an array. 
The problem with the second layer array is that I can't seem to use it. 
The JSON looks something like this:

```
{
  "section": "U.S.",
  "subsection": "Politics",
  "title": "To Understand Clinton’s Moment, Consider That It Came 32 Years After Ferraro’s",
  "abstract": "A look back to when Geraldine A. Ferraro was on the Democratic ticket in 1984 can tell a lot about how the country has changed, and how it has not.",
  "url": "urlLocation",
  "byline": "By ALISON MITCHELL",
  "item_type": "Article",
  "updated_date": "2016-06-11T13:17:01-04:00",
  "created_date": "2016-06-11T13:17:05-04:00",
  "published_date": "2016-06-12T00:00:00-04:00",
  "material_type_facet": "",
  "kicker": "",
  "des_facet": [
    "Presidential Election of 2016",
    "Women and Girls"
  ],
  "org_facet": [],
  "per_facet": [
    "Clinton, Hillary Rodham",
    "Ferraro, Geraldine A"
  ],
  "geo_facet": [],
  "multimedia": [
    {
      "url": "urlLocation",
      "format": "Standard Thumbnail",
      "height": 75,
      "width": 75,
      "type": "image",
      "subtype": "photo",
      "caption": "Geraldine A. Ferraro at a hearing of the Democratic national convention’s platform committee in 1984, the year she became the first woman selected to be a major party’s vice presidential nominee.",
      "copyright": "George Tames/The New York Times"
    },
    {
      "url": "urlLocation",
      "format": "thumbLarge",
      "height": 150,
      "width": 150,
      "type": "image",
      "subtype": "photo",
      "caption": "Geraldine A. Ferraro at a hearing of the Democratic national convention’s platform committee in 1984, the year she became the first woman selected to be a major party’s vice presidential nominee.",
      "copyright": "George Tames/The New York Times"
    },
    {
      "url": "urlLocation",
      "format": "Normal",
      "height": 127,
      "width": 190,
      "type": "image",
      "subtype": "photo",
      "caption": "Geraldine A. Ferraro at a hearing of the Democratic national convention’s platform committee in 1984, the year she became the first woman selected to be a major party’s vice presidential nominee.",
      "copyright": "George Tames/The New York Times"
    },
    {
      "url": "urlLocation",
      "format": "mediumThreeByTwo210",
      "height": 140,
      "width": 210,
      "type": "image",
      "subtype": "photo",
      "caption": "Geraldine A. Ferraro at a hearing of the Democratic national convention’s platform committee in 1984, the year she became the first woman selected to be a major party’s vice presidential nominee.",
      "copyright": "George Tames/The New York Times"
    },
    {
      "url": "urlLocation",
      "format": "superJumbo",
      "height": 1364,
      "width": 2048,
      "type": "image",
      "subtype": "photo",
      "caption": "Geraldine A. Ferraro at a hearing of the Democratic national convention’s platform committee in 1984, the year she became the first woman selected to be a major party’s vice presidential nominee.",
      "copyright": "George Tames/The New York Times"
    }
  ],
  "short_url": "urlLocation"
}
```

I tried accessing it like this:

```
NewsArticle newsArticle = new NewsArticle();
            newsArticle.category = data.results[counter].section;
            newsArticle.title = data.results[counter].title;
            newsArticle.fullText = data.results[counter].@abstract;
            DynamicJsonArray multimedia = data.results[counter].multimedia;
            newsArticle.image = multimedia[0].url;
            return_value.Add(newsArticle);
```

I get an "Index was outside the bounds of the array." exception on the "multimedia" array. Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Use Debugger, you probably not deserializing it correctly.

Comment: What is `counter` in your code? Please provide code you use for deserializing JSON.

Comment: I'm using the Sytem.Web.Helper library. In the root of the JSON file is given how many entries there are in this file, I store these in the counter variable.

Answer (score 0):

There seemed to be a problem in the return value of the service. The first result did not contain that array, that was why I got the index out of bounds exception.
Thanks Orel Eraki!